# Word above symbol in inline string in matplotlib title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create an informative title in my `matplotlib` plot. And this information I add together into one single string, which is the used to set the title of my plot. This "title" could look something like:

```
A  -->   B   -->   C   -->   D
```

Now, depending on various factors, I would like to have a small word above the arrow, which indicates something, for example:

```
   walk      bus      train
A  -->   B   -->   C   -->   D
```

First I tried to use LaTeX and `\overset`, but as of now, it doesn't seem to work until `matplotlib` is updated to 3.4 or something. In theory I could also calculate the characters, and then add a line above where the words would then be put almost in the right place, but I don't think that will be very pretty.

So is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Are you asking how to format a multiline string to use as a title? Have you tried a solution using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings); calculating widths and positions to determine where to but the characters in the top line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `\stackrel`? It works with Matplotlib 3.1.3 on my system:

```
plt.title(r'$A\stackrel{\mathrm{walk}}{\longrightarrow}B$')
plt.show()
```

**Update**: for Matplotlib 3.3:

```
plt.title(r'$A\genfrac{}{}{0}{}{\mathrm{walk}}{\longrightarrow}B$')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, it just says: `ValueError:
A\stackrel{\mathrm{walk}}{\longrightarrow}B
 ^
Unknown symbol: \stackrel, found '\'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)`

And I have 3.3

Comment: @DenverDang from the warning in my system `\stackrel` is being replaced by `\genfrac` in matplotlib 3.3. Somehow the warning shows itself this time but not the first time I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
params = {'text.latex.preamble' : [r'\usepackage{mathtools}', r'\usepackage{amsmath}', r'\usepackage{aligned-overset}']}
plt.rcParams.update(params)


# using some dummy data for this example
xs = np.random.randint( 0, 10, size=10)
ys = np.random.randint(-5, 5,  size=10)

# plot the points
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.title(r'$\mathbf{A  \buildrel{walk}\over{-->} B   \buildrel{bus}\over{-->}   C   \buildrel{train}\over{-->}   D}$', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(xs,ys,'b-')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=20)
plt.grid()
```

[image: LatesTitleImage]